# Photon Unity Networking: DefaultPool failed to load "playerPrefab"

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, photon-pun

I'm trying to instantiate a player using Photon in Unity 2D, but I'm encountering two errors that I can't seem to resolve:

Error 1: DefaultPool failed to load "playerPrefab". Make sure it's in a "Resources" folder. Or use a custom IPunPrefabPool.

I've double-checked that the playerPrefab is in a "Resources" folder, and the folder is named correctly. I'm not sure why this error is occurring.

Error 2: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpawner : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform[] spawners;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject playerPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(nameof(playerPrefab), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

I have ensured that all references are set in the Unity Editor, and the playerPrefab is assigned correctly. What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is your player prefab named "playerPrefab" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PreparePool : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<GameObject> Prefabs;

    private void Start() {
        DefaultPool pool = PhotonNetwork.PrefabPool as DefaultPool;
        if(pool != null && this.Prefabs != null)
        {
            foreach(GameObject prefab in this.Prefabs)
            {
                pool.ResourceCache.Add(prefab.name, prefab);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, ***Resource*** folder already added to ***PhotonNetwork.PrefabPool***.

You can fix this error if you use above code and There is no need to copy it to the resource folder.

Hope help this answer for you

Comment: It is working fine in my side. How about your result?